Create Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] by piping through InputStream
I need decompress data using compression not supported by akka, but supported by other library which provided InputStream interface.
To make it work with akka stream, I need to implement function:
def pipeThroughInputStream(pipeThrough: InputStream => InputStream): Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed]

But I'm not sure how to do it.
I'm aware about conversion functions like StreamConverters.asInputStream and StreamConverters.fromInputStream but I don't know how to apply them here. All I have come up with so far is
  def pipeThroughInputStream(pipeThrough: InputStream => InputStream): Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] = {
    val sink: Sink[ByteString, Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]]] = StreamConverters.asInputStream().mapMaterializedValue { materializedInputStream =>
      val inputStream = pipeThrough(materializedInputStream)
      StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => inputStream)
    }
    ???
  }

But I don't know how now convert this Sink that materializes to Source back to Flow.

Does your library only work with InputStream? Can't it work with String or byte[]? You moght want to convert a ByteString to it's byte array representation and then to a ByteArrayInputStream. I don't think you need StreamConverters method.

ByteString represents chunk of data. It doesn't work because we don't want to buffer and materialize the byte stream to byte array. And we also cannot process each chunk separately (because of specifics of this processing).
Side note, my specific goal is to use org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.CompressorStreamFactory.createCompressorInputStream to decompress byte stream with algorithm not supported by akka.

You don't want a Flow[ByteString, ByteString, _] then. Using asInputStreamwill give you anInputStream` and you can give it to your library.

Flow[ByteString, ByteString, _] Is a common interface that I created, I'm using in multiple places and need to implement for this case here.

What you'll want is something along the lines of this:
def pipeThroughInputStream(pipeThrough: InputStream => InputStream)(implicit mat: Materializer): Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] = {
  val sink = StreamConverters.asInputStream().mapMaterializedValue { materializedInputStream =>
    val inputStream = pipeThrough(materializedInputStream)
    StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => inputStream)
  }
  val (source, matSink) = sink.preMaterialize()
  Flow.fromSinkAndSource(matSink, source)
}

Pre-materializing lets us get at the source we're materializing.  We then use fromSinkAndSource to create a flow which uses the sink as its sink side and the source as its source side.  In this case, they are decoupled: the downstream canceling will not stop the upstream (this may not be a problem with a finite source or if there's some means to stop the upstream like a KillSwitch)... fromSinkAndSourceCoupled will couple these, but that will also cause the downstream to complete when the upstream completes, potentially before what happens in "InputStreamland" is done.  If one wanted something more aware of the state of the InputStream, one could implement a custom stage with the desired reactive stream semantics.
Note that pre-materializing will do all the InputStream wiring before the rest of the stream materializes (i.e. when you're building the "blueprint" for the stream).  If that's undesirable, you can be a little more obscure by replacing the last pair of lines with something like:
Flow.lazyFlow { () =>
  Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled(sink, sink.preMaterialize())
}

This will delay doing the InputStream wiring until there is demand from downstream.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Here is standalone example:
https://gist.github.com/Vistritium/2c61da8765788c4b1586cba60a125196

How so?  What do you end up with for output?  If you have an empty output, try fromSinkAndSource (as the empty output could be from closing the outlet as soon as the inlet completes).

You are correct, that was one of the issues. I now progressed with this issue. My current version is: https://gist.github.com/Vistritium/9d0ab78d25b338ffbb851807a423110f
But it's still not working. It outputs the input, it doesn't use the provided input stream at all. In this example, I created an input stream that should remove "0" bytes from the stream. I also put println in read function, but it's not invoked at all.
Side question: preMaterialize returns another sink, and I end up with 2 sinks. Which one to use? (only the one returned by preMaterialize seems to be working)

Actually it works. I incorrectly implemented the FilterInputStream

One more thing: I'm trying to use lazyFlow and my problem is that it changes the materialized type from NotUsed to Future[NotUsed]. But I need just NotUsed in this interface. Any idea what to do with it? Here is my current function version that uses lazyFlow and just disregards the Future and it's result.
https://gist.github.com/Vistritium/e87bcbc0442b2fe7a0835e1606d05fc5
Is that correct?

If you don't care about the materialized Future[NotUsed] (which is only marginally more useful than NotUsed: it can be "not yet NotUsed" as well as NotUsed), you can just mapMaterializedValue(_ => NotUsed).

Future can also fail and I was scared that I might be ignoring/swallowing some errors with this approach.
